# What is the most efficient way to gain fame?

Tags: realm-of-the-mad-god

With all the bonuses that Realm of the Mad God offers, in what order should I gain each achievement?  What is the most efficient way to gain the most fame in a lifetime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, for one, keep in mind you have to **die** to collect any fame that's been earned.  But, if you're looking to just pad your reputation then I suppose you wouldn't have asked anyway.

[This page](https://forums.wildshadow.com/wiki/realm-mad-god/fame-bonuses) tells you exactly how your fame is calculated.  I won't transcribe it, but pertaining to your question, it kind of matters how you plan on playing your *current* life.

If you're looking to make this character last as long as possible, I would try to touch on them all, i.e. ***Slayer of the Gods***, ***Cartographer***, ***Leader of Men***, ***Well Equipped***, ***etc***.

If you're looking for a quick blast of Fame, then get your character to a decent level and go for the high fame percentages, i.e. ***Oryx Killer***, ***Boots on the Ground***, etc.

Also, keep in mind that once you hit level 20, you receive fame for every kill you make, albeit quite a lot smaller than XP dealt when under 20.

There are plenty of Fame-farming guides on Youtube ([zxcv](http://youtu.be/bqWl3b9if5Y), [aratar](http://youtu.be/MPbkLU7Pg9g)) as well.

Hope that helps...fame is a tricky beast and from what I've been hearing on the forums/Reddit threads...it is due for an upcoming revamp, so take what you will from this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I heard that Fame bonuses apply instantly when you get them, for example, if you're at 140 fame when you get Cartographer, it applies the bonus from there, adding 10% of 140, instead of your total. That's why I was looking for the best way to gain those achievements to not have wasted fame.

Comment: Well you do get fame in your little orange progress bar, but it doesn't dump into your reputation until you die :)

Comment: With the new fame upgrades, fame is applied at the end of your death, applying the bonus percentages to the total fame you earned.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to get fame just go out to the center aka "God Lands" and kill anything that moves, but I would reccomend lvl 16 for lower Gods and 20 for the all out GODS.